# Dynamically update python property setter method

Tags: python, dynamic, properties, mixins, duck-typing

I am trying to dynamically add a 'lockable' feature on a value.  While this particular case seems trivial or rather contrived, I want to expand my lockable mix-in class for a variety of different use-cases.  I do not want to make a one-off lockable value; I want this to be generic enough to control any number of class attributes.

My expectation after I am done is that the last assertion will pass.

I had tried using super instead of self.**setattr**, but I received an error that the attribute was read-only.  And that makes me wonder if I can even do what I'd like to do.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Some code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict as OD


def lockable(func, locked=None):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        if locked:
            val = None
        else:
            val = func(*args, **kwds)
        return val
    return wrapper


class Mixin(object):

    @property
    def meta(self):
        attr = "__meta__"
        if not hasattr(self, attr):
            setattr(self, attr, OD())
        return getattr(self, attr)


class LockableMixin(Mixin):

    @property
    def locked(self):
        self.meta.setdefault("locked", False)
        return self.meta.get("locked")

    @locked.setter
    def locked(self, value):
        value = value if value in [None, True, False] else self.meta['locked']
        self.meta['locked'] = value

    def lock(self):
        self.locked = True

    def unlock(self):
        self.locked = False

    def is_locked(self):
        return self.locked

    def __init__(self):
        super(LockableMixin, self).__init__()
        self.__setattr__ = lockable(self.__setattr__, self.locked)


class Attribute(object):

    @property
    def value(self):
        attr = "__value__"
        if not hasattr(self, attr):
            setattr(self, attr, False)
        return getattr(self, attr)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self.__value__ = value

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        super(Attribute, self).__init__()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        cname = self.__class__.__name__
        value = str(self.value)
        return "<%s %s>" % (cname, value)


class LockableAttribute(Attribute, LockableMixin):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a1 = Attribute(1)
    a2 = LockableAttribute(1)
    assert a2.locked is False
    assert a2.value == 1
    a2.lock()
    assert a2.locked is True
    a2.unlock()
    assert a2.locked is False
    a2.value = 2
    assert a2.value == 2
    a2.locked = True
    a2.value = 3
    assert a2.value == 2    # This will raise an exception, but it shouldn't.
```

Here's more of a use case for a component class:

```
class Component(object):

    @property
    def attributes(self):
        attrs = {}
        for field in self.__fields__:
            attrs[field] = self.get(field)
        return attrs

    def __init__(self, **attributes):
        super(Component, self).__init__()
        self.__fields__ = []
        for name, val in attributes.iteritems():
            if name not in self.__fields__:
                self.__fields__.append(name)
                setattr(self, name, val)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if not name.startswith("__"):
            if not isinstance(value, Attribute):
                value = Attribute(value)
        super(Component, self).__setattr__(name, value)

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name, None)

    def get(self, name, default=None):
        return getattr(self, name, default)

# Case 1:  a lockable attribute
c = Component(name="Joe Schmoe", dob=LockableDateAttribute("04/12/2014"))

c.dob.lock()
c.dob.unlock()

# Case 2:  a lockable component class containing arbitrary number of lockable attributes
c2 = LockableComponent(name="Jill Pill", dob=LockableDateAttribute("04/12/2014))
c2.lock()   #  locks all of the lockable attributes
```

Comment: Interesting exercise :) Let my try to understand... So do you want to lock one attribute in particular within a class with any number of attributes?

Comment: In a word: Yes.

I'm envisioning a Component with a set of attributes where I could lock the Component up, including all of its attributes (likely a list, tuple or set).  I'd like to have the Attributes all be compatible to some degree with each other.  But some might be lockable.  Some might be disabled...etc.

Comment: Wait... if you're locking a2 when its value is 2, why would assert `a2.value == 2` fail? Did you mean `assert a2.value == 3` would fail?

Comment: If a2.value was 2, and then it was locked, I shouldn't be able to set it to a2.value of 3.  Instead, it should simply ignore that set and keep the value at 2 instead of updating to a value of 3.

Comment: Ohhh... So *"this will fail"* means that is actually raising the assertion (because a2.value is 3) Well, that's what I though, anyway... **:-)** Let me know what do you think about my answer

Comment: This is sort of where I am going with the whole thought process...

https://github.com/brianbruggeman/dynamic_property/tree/develop

Comment: Hmmm... Would you like to wrap all the attributes of the class into `LockableAttributes`? If that's the case, that can be done through metaclasses, but don't think it's good idea to do that. I'll be really confusing for whomever uses your code (he believed he was setting a `a.x = 5` to be an `int` and then all the sudden is not an `int` but a `LockableAttribute` that he needs to access through `a.x.value` instead of just `a.x`?

Comment: I think the __ get __ can alleviate at least part of that problem (though I admit I haven't actually tested that much).

Comment: How would `c.dob` would be used? Would you mind adding a few lines to that update so I can see it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant acceded (if it's not locked, would you do `c.dob.value = "05/01/2015"`)?

Comment: Yes, I think that would make perfect sense.

Comment: Dang, I'm out... (at least for now)!! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last assert in your sample code is a typo, and you were trying to make sure that `a2.value` wasn't `3` because it had been locked on the line before, how about making the `value` of the `LockableAttribute` a descriptor?

I've created a `Foo` class that uses `LockableAttribute`s and has one method to lock all the `LockableAttribute`s and another to unlock them all. Something like what you said in your comment about *envisioning a Component with a set of attributes where I could lock the Component up*:

```
class LockableValue(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__['value']
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not(instance.locked):
            instance.__dict__['value'] = value

class LockableAttribute(object):
    value = LockableValue()
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.locked = False
        self.value = value
    def lock(self):
        self.locked = True
    def unlock(self):
        self.locked = False

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = LockableAttribute()
        self.b = LockableAttribute()
    def lock_all(self):
        for k, v in vars(self).iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, LockableAttribute):
                v.lock()
    def unlock_all(self):
        for k, v in vars(self).iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, LockableAttribute):
                v.unlock()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo.a.value = 1
    foo.b.value = "hello"
    assert foo.a.locked is False
    assert foo.a.value == 1
    assert foo.b.locked is False
    assert foo.b.value == "hello"
    foo.lock_all()
    assert foo.a.locked is True
    assert foo.b.locked is True
    foo.a.unlock()
    assert foo.a.locked is False
    assert foo.b.locked is True
    foo.a.value = 2
    assert foo.a.value == 2
    foo.a.value += 1
    assert foo.a.value == 3
    foo.a.locked = True
    foo.a.value = 4
    print "foo.a.value: %s" % foo.a.value
    assert foo.a.value == 4
```

That seems to do what you asked for... No? I don't know, maybe I misunderstood something, though. If that's the case, let me know (I'm pretty curious about descriptors and metaclasses myself)

It outputs:

```
foo.a.value: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stack31.py", line 56, in <module>
    assert foo.a.value == 4
AssertionError
```

Comment: I like this answer, but it's not generic enough.  I want the mixin to modify the setter for all of the attributes.  I probably should have gone to the trouble of laying it out like this, because I think it will help me arrive at the answer I'm looking for.  I'll add a component class in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works:

```
def lockable(func):
    def _lockable(self, *args, **kwds):
        locked = getattr(self, 'locked', None)
        val = None if locked else func(self, *args, **kwds)
        return val
    return _lockable


class LockableMixin(Mixin):

    @property
    def locked(self):
        value = None
        if hasattr(self, 'meta'):
            self.meta.setdefault("locked", False)
            value = self.meta.get("locked")
        return value

    @locked.setter
    def locked(self, value):
        locked = None
        if hasattr(self, 'locked'):
            if value in [None, True, False]:
                locked = value
            self.meta['locked'] = locked

    def lock(self):
        self.locked = True

    def unlock(self):
        self.locked = False

    def is_locked(self):
        return self.locked

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        func = super(LockableMixin, self).__setattr__
        locked = getattr(self, 'locked', None)
        if not locked or name == 'locked':
            func(name, value)

    def __init__(self):
        super(LockableMixin, self).__init__()
```